# Infinite sums of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers. Is it true that

$   $\begin{equation*}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n < \epsilon \text{ for all }  N \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \le \epsilon ? \end{equation*}$   $

This should be true intuitively, but I am having trouble proving it by contradiction. If at infinity, the sum is strictly greater than some $\epsilon$, can I conclude at some finite point the sum was greater than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Hint:  The value of a convergent series (when it exists)  is defined to be limit of the sequence of partial sums.

Comment: If the series converges, even if it has negative terms, as long as the inequality holds for infinitely $N$ the theorem of the permanence of the sign (the one for sequences) justify your assertion

Answer (score 2):

This is a more general fact. If a sequence is (strictly) bounded, and has a limit, then its limit must satisfy the same bound. Here the sequence under consideration is the sequence of partial sums.

And yes, your idea will work in order to prove this more general fact as well. In fact, by definition of convergence, your assumption would imply that infinitely often, the partial sums hit a value greater than epsilon.

Answer (score 1):

The *definition* of the notation $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is $\lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n$.
So this follows from the more general fact that $s_N < \varepsilon$ for all $N$ implies $\lim_{N\to\infty} s_N \le \varepsilon$.